# error when reading a file from stdin

Tags: c

the following code is to read  file from stdin but it cant find the file and I cant find the error. Can someone help.

```
FILE *file; 
char filename[200];// "ROMAN_in.txt";
char buffer[1000];

if (fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin) == NULL) // from 
stdin(keyboard) to store it in filename 
{
    printf("Error");
    return 1; 
}

file = fopen(filename, "r");

if (file == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "File %s not found\n", filename);
    return 1;
}
else
{
    while (fgets(buffer, strlen(buffer), file) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have the `main` function, so that's a one big error.

Comment: I know, I just didn't copy it

Comment: do not use `strlen(buffer)`, but `sizeof buffer`

Comment: "*cant find the file"*. You forgot to remove the trailing newline from `filename` input by `fgets`. Please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: As in the answer, `strlen(buffer)` is worked on an *uninitialised variable*.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
while (fgets(buffer, strlen(buffer), file) != NULL)
```

looks like `strlen(buffer)` returns 0 since `buffer` in not explicitly initialized global array. Thus it is initialized to 0s. So `strlen` will return 0.

Probably in your case you should use `sizeof(buffer)`.

P.S.

Try using debugger. You will immediately see in what `if` condition it goes to the unexpected path.

*Edit 1:*

Of course, as mentioned by **Weather Vane** in the comments, `fgets` returns the string with the `\n` character (Enter key). You need to get rid of it before using it as a filename ([Howto link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)).

Comment: thanks I changed that but I when  I use fopen to open the file, it returns null and printd file not found. Maybe I have to input the filename differently?

Comment: @pteran I see that 'Weather Vane' wrote you in the comment that you need to get rid of the trailing '\n' after using `fgets` for getting the filename. He is right.